# dolphin emulator (development version)

Tags: ppa, repository, emulation

i'm trying to setup dolphin emulator on ubuntu, as it was working fine on manjaro. the dolphin stable version is working fine but i need the development version for vulkan support i believe. tried inputting:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install dolphin-emu-master
```

as explained in [dolphin wiki](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Installing_Dolphin#Ubuntu)

but i get an error outputted: Unable to locate package dolphin-emu-master

kubuntu 20.04.
the stable version installs just fine both via terminal and store GUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, the error message I received was: ERROR: ppa 'dolphin-emu/ppa' not found (use --login if private)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dolphin-emu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you used does not contain a valid version for *ubuntu 20.04, the last one indicated is 18.10

At the moment, the only way to install the development version, seems to be to compile the source code as described in the GIT repository: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin#building-for-linux-and-macos.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the PPA. Use the snap package instead.

```
sudo snap install dolphin-emulator --edge
```

or alternatively to install the stable version of Dolphin Emulator:

```
sudo snap install dolphin-emulator
```

Comment: The [last stable version, v5, is currently 6+ years old.](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/) The edge version seems to work on 22.04 and currently gives developer version 5.017893 which is only a couple of months old.